# cordova plugins issue, not running

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am making an android app with cordova, I have installed the following :-

```
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-sms-plugin 1.0.0 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
```

I have the app running fine apart from the toast and SMS plugin dont work? So I am thinking, is everything else working? Because it runs in webview, maybe its working with the JS libraries I have added. When I test it locally it can't find the cordova.js script but from what I have read it assigns this on build.

I get this error

```
index.html:86 GET file:///C:/Users/Zak/Desktop/cordova/app/location/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

All the files are installed and are in place from what I can see but when I call toast or sms I get errors. Shall I add it to my www folder and copy the files required or will this mess thing up?

Any ideas?

Comment: chamber can you explode the debug apk and check cordova.js file is available under www folder?

Comment: Yes its in the www folder

Comment: I have it working now, I was adding it in the wrong place but now I am getting a message saying user id denying permssion, how do I add permission?

Comment: what do you really mean by added it in wrong place

Comment: I added the code to my page instead of in to app{} and also got permission working by adding this to the android.json ,
            {
              "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS\" />",
              "count": 1
            },
            {
              "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.READ_SMS\" />",
              "count": 1
            },
            {
              "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.SEND_SMS\" />",
              "count": 1
            }

Comment: Glad that you got it working